# How do i deploy office 365 in my organisation?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

Ok, this is probably a simple problem but i am going to ask anyway.

We are a small enterprise of +- 250 users. We are migrating to office 365 and all active directory accounts will be known by two ADFS servers to allow people to connect from anywhere using their credentials.

But we have to install office 365 on all the internal computers. As far as i know (and i still don't have the licences so i can't test it) people will have to use their company mail address to register themselves on office 365 ?

Basically their mail address is their login i suppose.
So does this mean everyone will have to connect to the office 365 webpage to register with their mail adresses and install it themselves or can i install a basis on every pc that asks them for their mail address and then install the office 365 suite from the internet automatically ?

Sorry if this sounds stupid, i am but a normal helpdesk employee trying to understand what has to be done ;)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy Office 365 to your organization, you should purchase license and assign license to users. You can add the display names and user names of your employees or other people who will use Office 365 with you, which I think can be the user's email account. Just referring to this: [Set up Office 365 for business](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/setup/setup?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=BusPremium).

After the users have been assigned license, they can sign in [www.office.com](https://www.office.com/?auth=2) to install Office 365. Please refer to [Download and install or reinstall Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-365-or-office-2019-on-a-pc-or-mac-4414eaaf-0478-48be-9c42-23adc4716658?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)